# Can't set multiple choice selection in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, contacts

I'm having problems with setting multiple choice selection in ListView. My ListView has contacts' names which are retrieved from the android phone.

I've followed examples on setting multiple choice but it didn't work out.

I've tried typing

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_list, c, columns, views);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

but I don't see the checkbox in the ListView.

And I've replaced `R.layout.contacts_list` with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` and it showed checkboxes but no names from the android phone's contacts.

Here are my codes:
contacts_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/light_goldenrod"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/dark_purple"
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

ContactsList.java

```
public class ContactsList extends ListActivity
{
    final Context context = this;

    Cursor cursor;

    String[] buddiesList = 
        {"Kanak Priya",
        "Joanne Liew",
        "Michelle Lam",
        "Teo Kin Hua",
        "Melissa Haiting",
        "David Yeo",
        "Natasha Akhbar",
        "Gillian Gan",
        "Sonia",
        "Ms Long",
        "Joan Tang",
        "Stephanie",
        "Nur Ashiqin"
        };

    BuddyDBAdapter buddyDB = new BuddyDBAdapter(this);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list);

        ListView list = getListView();



        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.contacts_list, R.id.contactName, buddiesList));

        Uri allContacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");

        Cursor c = managedQuery(allContacts, null, null, null, null);

        String[] columns = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
        int[] views = new int[]  {R.id.contactName};

        startManagingCursor(c);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_list, c, columns, views);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);


        /*if(cursor.getCount()<0)
        {
            Intent displayIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            displayIntent.setData(Uri.parse("content://contacts/people"));
            startActivity(displayIntent);

            displayIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            //displayIntent.setData(Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/"+id));
            startActivity(displayIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("ALERT!");
            alertDialog.setMessage("NO Name is Found! D:");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.warning);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    Intent backIntent = new Intent(context, ContactsList.class);
                    startActivity(backIntent);
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        buddyDB.open();
        long name_id;
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


        Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();

        TextView contactName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        String NameValue = contactName.getText().toString();

        name_id = buddyDB.insertNames(NameValue);


        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Selected: " + buddiesList[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        buddyDB.close();
```

Oh by the way, the

```
String[] buddiesList = 
        {"Kanak Priya",
        "Joanne Liew",
        "Michelle Lam",
        "Teo Kin Hua",
        "Melissa Haiting",
        "David Yeo",
        "Natasha Akhbar",
        "Gillian Gan",
        "Sonia",
        "Ms Long",
        "Joan Tang",
        "Stephanie",
        "Nur Ashiqin"
        };
```

is for my Toast message.

I really need help with this. Any help will be appreciated. Examples will be greatly appreciated too.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have two choices:

**1 - Use default layout from Android resources (simple_list_item_multiple_choice)**

you may replace this code:

> ```
> SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.contacts_list, c, columns, views);
> ```

to:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, c, columns, new int {android.R.id.text1});
```

**2 - Create your new row layout contains your defined checkbox and handle it by your own.**

contact_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/light_goldenrod"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

contact_entry.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/dark_purple"
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/contactCheckbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:checked="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Add custom cursor adapter like this:

```
public class YourCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter  {

private Context mContext;
private Cursor mCurser;

public YourCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
        int[] to, ContentResolver co) {
    super(context, c);
    mCurser = c;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_entry, parent, false);
    bindView(v, mContext, cursor);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView contactName= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
    contactName.setText(cursor.getString((mCurser
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME))));
    CheckBox contactCheckbox = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactCheckbox);
    contactCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Checkbox checkBox = (Checkbox) v.findViewById(R.id.contactCheckbox)
            if (checkBox.isChecked())
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
            else
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }
    });
}
```

in your ListActivity:

```
    YourCursorAdapter adapter = new YourCursorAdapter(this,
            null, c, null, null,null);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: hi, i'll try out your codes. if i've any problems i'll let you know. thanks for your answer.

Comment: do I need to create `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` in the Android resources -- res folder?

Comment: no. But it will come with default listview's row of Android system. If you want implement your own listview's row, you have to re-define contacts_list.xml in res/layout folder by adding checkbox to it.

Comment: i've added the checkbox to the listview. but the checkbox is at the bottom of the listview. i don't want it to be at the bottom of listview and i want only to be below each name. i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: there are some strange things in your contacts_list.xml. you should create your listview's row  in seperate layout with the listview.

Comment: See my update answer. You may need some corrects to make it works.